# Maximum request length exceeded despite setting both maxRequestLength and maxAllowedContentLength

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

I've got an Azure Cloud Service (Web Role), and am posting a 5MB video to a WebApi controller class that hands off the request (which is a MIME multipart body request, with form data as well as a 2nd smaller JPG file that's 32KB). I'm using a custom MultipartFormDataStreamProvider implementation that saves the files to disk.

Works great with files under 4MB. But even after adding the following to my web.config file, I get the maximum length exceeded exception (within a "Error reading MIME multipart body part." exception). I'm running in debug mode, and it fails both within the local Azure emulator or when I startup the Cloud Service locally without the Azure emulator. It's driving me nuts and wasting hours of time trying to figure out why this is happening.

```
    <security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>

  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength ="1048576" executionTimeout="3600"/>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this might help or not. But I had written a blog 2 years back on uploading larger than 4MB files. Basically some more configuration elements in Metabase.xml file need to be updated in order to allow larger files to be transmitted. Check out this link : http://amoghnatu.wordpress.com/2012/08/19/49/

Comment: Thanks but I'm thinking since Azure is using IIS7, that this wouldn't apply right?

Comment: Search for the IIS7 equivalent for those terms in Metabase.xml

Comment: @Whookie did you manage to solve this problem? My team is facing similar issue.